# iOS keyboard keys move off top of screen

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, uikit, ios-simulator

I've inherited a partially finished app that I need to finish. Unfortunately there seems to be a bug involving the display of the keyboard. The bug does not occur when opening the app on my iPhone, but it does appear in the simulator, and I'm being told it also appears on iPad.

When selecting a text field on the affected , the keyboard background rolls up in the right spot. However, the keyboard buttons appear near the top of the screen, and then rolls up until they can no longer be seen. If another text field is selected, the keyboard buttons appear so that they are visible, but still at the top of the screen, instead of down on the keyboard background. The problem can be seen in this video:

https://vid.me/0bEs

I've searched through the code, and I can't find anything overt that should cause this behaviour. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post code where the keyboard/textfields are being used.

Comment: Well, part of the reason that I'm having so much trouble finding the problem, is that I don't seem to have any code related to the keyboard. And any use of the textfields are primarily about getting the inputted text, once a button is pressed. It is a semi-large project, so there might be some code that I'm not seeing. But I can't give you what I can't find.

Comment: Are any of the `UITextField` delegate methods implemented? If so post them. Can you also search your project for any UIKeyboard notifications that are listed here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/index.html

Comment: Okay, I'm concentrating my investigation on one specific viewcontroller. That viewcontroller has no UITextField delegates. I do have UIKeyboard notifications on one category in the project (and I searched the entire project for the notifications), but that category isn't being used by the viewcontroller that I'm looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check in appdelegate or in view controller that is there any observer with selector method. I generally face such issue while working on some other person's code.

Just search in through out project UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification, UIKeyboardDidShowNotification.

Hope you will get something so we can solve this riddle.

Comment: There are no UIKeyboard anything in the app, except for the notifications on the unused category mentioned in the comments of my question. My appdelegate doesn't seem to provide any answers either. The only thing I would suspect was that we were using the https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck code to display a sliding side menu. But even after I removed that from the app, the keyboard was still wonky.